# data not being added to arrayList

Tags: java

I'm having troubling with my java code. For some reason my attributes that i'm trying to add to a list is sort of working, but it only keeps or shows the object in the list. I dont know if the attributes are being erased or what but it's really annoying.

```
public static Program parseProgram(File fileName)
        throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner in1 = new Scanner(fileName);

    Program program = new Program();
    Short value = 0;
    Short address = 0;
    boolean indirect = false;
    String[] temp = null;

    while (in1.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = in1.nextLine();
        temp = line.split("\\s+");

        Scanner in2 = new Scanner(temp[0]);

        if (in2.hasNextInt(16)) {
            int temp1 = Integer.parseInt(temp[0]);
            Short temp2 = (short) temp1;
            int temped = Integer.parseInt(temp[1]);
            Short temp3 = (short) temped;
            DataLine data = new DataLine(temp2, temp3);
            try {
                program.addDataLine(data);
            } catch (DataAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            String s = "*";
            String ss = new String();

            Instruction instruction = Instruction.getByName(temp[0]);

            if (instruction.requiresArgument()) {
                int temped = Integer.parseInt(temp[1], 16);
                Short arg = (short) temped;
                if (temp.length > 1) {
                    if (temp[1].endsWith("*")) {
                        indirect = true;
                        ss = temp[1].substring(0, temp[1].indexOf("*"));
                        arg = (short) Integer.parseInt(ss);
                        CodeLine code = new CodeLine(instruction, arg,
                                indirect);
                        try {
                            program.addCodeLine(code);
                        } catch (CodeAccessException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else if (line.contains(s)) {
                        indirect = true;
                        String sg = temp[1].substring(0,
                                temp[1].indexOf("*"));
                String st = temp[1]
                                .substring(temp[1].indexOf("*") + 1);
                        ss = sg + st;
                        arg = (short) Integer.parseInt(ss);
                CodeLine code = new CodeLine(instruction, arg);
                        try {
                            program.addCodeLine(code);
                        } catch (CodeAccessException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated  catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("error");
                }
            }

            else {
                CodeLine code = new CodeLine(instruction);
                try {
                    program.addCodeLine(code);
                } catch (CodeAccessException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

    }
    return program;

}
```

}
}

public class Program implements Serializable{

```
private List<CodeLine> codeSegment = new ArrayList<CodeLine>();

private List<DataLine> dataSegment = new ArrayList<DataLine>();

/**
 * Add a line of code to this program.
 * 
 * @param line must not be null.
 * @throws CodeAccessException if line is null
 */
public void addCodeLine(CodeLine line) throws CodeAccessException{
    if(line == null)
        throw new CodeAccessException("Cannot add null code lines to a program.");
    codeSegment.add(line);
}

/**
 * Add a data instructionn to this program.  A data instruction is
 * a address - value pair.
 * 
 * @param line must not be null.
 * @throws DataAccessException if line is null
 */
public void addDataLine(DataLine line) throws DataAccessException{
    if(line == null)
        throw new DataAccessException("Cannot add null data lines to a program.");
    dataSegment.add(line);
}
```

Comment: What ArrayList are you talking about? There's no ArrayList declared in that block of code. Also, which object are you referring to? Could you show the code for that object too?

Comment: dataLine & codeLine are being added to program. But when i print the contents of the program I only get the piece of information from the file.

Comment: I can find many WTF with this code, notably using a `Scanner` to test if `temp[0]` is a string, and then parsing `temp[1]` without validating it's type.. and casting both of them as `short` into separate variables? etc.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to rewrite this whole thing from scratch. Really. Trash this code and rewrite it fresh.

Comment: well i'm on a time a contraint. The code works its just not keeping the contents somewhere the information is being erased because i'm only getting the information from the last object in the list

Comment: btw the this code is checking for strings and digits possibly seperated by *

Comment: then post the code from your Program class, keeping only the necessary methods and properties. And perhaps even a sample of the file you're reading. Because your question title is totally unrelated with your code and, worst, your problem, apparently is  unrelated with the code you posted.

Comment: I Just added the program code. Here are what the file contents look like LOD 0
STO 1
LOD 0
SUBI 1
STO 0
CMPZ 0
SUBI 1
JMPZ B
LOD 0
MUL 1
JUMP 1
HALT
0 7

Comment: oh! Assembly, you're making a parser?

Comment: yes btw this is my output  Program codeSegment=[instr=HALT, arg=0, indirect=false,], dataSegment=[DataLine address= 0, value= 7]

Comment: Funny, when I try to run the code you provide, there nothing in `program`. Is the whole code on one single line?

Comment: Here is what I tried to reproduce. It's fully runnable. http://shrib.com/vqtQwEjf

Comment: Thanks apparently the solution was in the part that focused on the codeLine specifically. I guess there was an issue with the indexing or overall check.